# How to see unserialised/decoded cookie value instead of unserialized value in chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, firebug

In chrome, I can see cookies in Application section but it's showing raw data as follows:
[image: Current in Dev tools]

But I want it to see the value, not raw data, I mean the data in form of array or JSON, is this possible in chrome? It's very easy in **Firebug** but I want to stick with chrome. Suggest here.

**Firebug View**
[image: Firebug view]

Actually here I need decoded value having

- %3A==> :
- %7B==> {
- %22==> "
- %3B==> ;
- %7D==> }

Comment: In the chrome console try doing: `document.cookie` to view the cookie contents

Comment: It's not working as it's showing all the cookies with the raw data value, I can see it in Dev tools easily. But I want to see the value, not the raw data.

Comment: Actually here I need decoded value having %3A==> :      ,    %7B==> {   ,  %22==> "     ,    %3B==> ;     ,   %7D==> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not developed yet in Chrome, So I opened a ticket at Chromium and it was implemented after a year in next releases.

**Link to the ticket:** https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=997625

Now I have the required feature in Chrome and Edge Browsers also.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tab => Application => Storage => Cookies

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am here but able to see the raw data value, But I want to see the decoded unserialized value like as firebug.